# JQuery slider by changing left absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

So I had the idea to try to make an image slider where instead of fading in and out the sliders just move into place one by one, this is by adding 450px (width of each image slider).

However I'm struggling on how to accomplish this,I want to check wether the slider is the last so that the the slider reverts back to the first and starts again.

This is the code I came up with so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var interval = 5000;//will move to left 450px each X seconds
    var sliders = $('.slider_image');//counts number of sliders
    var index = 0;
    var show_index = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        if(show_index == (sliders.length- 1))
        {
            $('.sliders_container').animate({ 'left': '0px'}, 2000);
        }
  else
        { 
            $('.sliders_container').animate({ 'left': '+=450px'}, 1000);
        }
    }, interval);
});
```

```css
/*SECTION SLIDER MARG START*/
.section_slider_marg_maincontainer{width:100%; height:275px; outline:2px solid white; position:relative;  overflow:hidden;}
.section_slider_marg_items_container{width:auto; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; display:flex; }
.section_slider_marg_item{height:100%; width:450px; outline:2px solid white; background-size:cover; }
/*SECTION SLIDER MARG END*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section_slider_marg_maincontainer" style="">
    <div class="section_slider_marg_items_container sliders_container" style="">
     <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');"></div>
     <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');"></div>
     <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing increment of `show_index` at each iteration: `show_index++` or `show_index--`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the Slick JQuery library for this. You can view it here:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I edited the `index.html` file that they provided and here is what I ended up with (this will only work if you have the Slick library downloaded):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Slick Playground</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick-theme.css">
  <style type="text/css">



  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <section class="carousel">
   
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">

      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">

      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">

      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">

      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">

      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">

      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7">

      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8">

      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9">

  </section>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
        $(".carousel").slick({
            dots: true
      });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Toms was saying, each time you animate, you should increment a variable to keep track.

This probably is not the most elegant solution, but it uses your same code setup.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var interval = 5000;//will move to left 450px each X seconds
var sliders = $('.slider_image');//counts number of sliders
var index = 0;
var show_index = 0;
var scrolledPx = 0;

setInterval(function() {

    if(scrolledPx >= 450 * sliders.length - 1) {

        $('.sliders_container').animate({ 'left': '0px'}, 2000);
        scrolledPx = 0;

    }

    else{

        $('.sliders_container').animate({ 'left': '+=450px'}, 1000);
        scrolledPx += 450;
    }

}, interval);
});
```